# FitClient: external process terminated before a connection could be established

Tags: fitnesse, fitsharp

On executing a simple Fitnesse test, I am getting the error :

> "FitClient: external process terminated before a connection could be
>   established."

On the Fitnesse server, the error is:

> "software caused connection abort socket write error"

.Net version used - 4.0

The contents on the page :

```
!define COMMAND_PATTERN {%m -r fitnesse.fitserver.FitServer, dotnet2\fit.dll %p}
!define TEST_RUNNER {dotnet2\Runner.exe}
```

Has anyone encountered this issue and also can anyone let me know how this can be fixed

Error

> System.ArgumentException: String cannot have zero length.    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String
>   codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName
>   assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadFrom(String
>   assemblyFile, Evidence securityEvidence, Byte[] hashValue,
>   AssemblyHashAlgorithm hashAlgorithm, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)    at
>   System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(String assemblyFile)    at
>   fitSharp.Machine.Engine.CurrentDomain.LoadAssembly(String
>   assemblyPath)    at
>   fitSharp.Machine.Engine.ApplicationUnderTest.Assemblies.AddAssembly(String
>   assemblyName)    at fitSharp.Machine.Application.Shell.Execute()    at
>   fitSharp.Machine.Application.Shell.Run(IList`1 commandLineArguments)

Comment: Is this all the time, or sometimes? I believe I have seen something similar recently (using Slim with Java), but it's not happening all the time just once every so often...

Comment: I am trying to set up fitnesse. This is happening all the time.

Comment: Just wanted to update. At that time the issue was fixed after unblocking(Right Click -> Properities -> Unblock) the fit.dlls

Answer (score 2):

I've been getting this same message for an absolutely trival test:

```
!path lib/*.jar
```

I was running DbFit for the first time.

I turned on verbose logging by including -v in the .bat file as follows:

```
java -cp "lib\dbfit-docs-3.2.0.jar;lib\fitnesse-20150424-standalone.jar" fitnesseMain.FitNesseMain -v %*
```

and noticed that there were spaces in the path showing up in the 3rd parameter in the `Starting Process` parameter list of .jar files. This was causing the initial call to fitnesse to fail, which resulted in the error message.

I fixed this by moving my DbFit installation to a folder without spaces: C:\dbfit. This resolved the issue.

On to the next issue now...

Hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the space after the comma in:

```
-r fitnesse.fitserver.FitServer, dotnet2\fit.dll
```

Actually, with recent versions of fitSharp, you don't need to specify the fit.dll. You can just use:

```
-r fitnesse.fitserver.FitServer
```

Answer (score 1):

I added an app.config file to the FitNesse runner.exe and everything started working.

1. Go to the directory where you have the Runner.exe installed
2. add a text (config) file named `runner.exe.config`
3. add the following xml to it so that when runner.exe starts it will be allowed to load the fit.dll.

   <configuration>
      <runtime>
         <loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true"/>
      </runtime>
   </configuration>

Run your tests again and they should work.

Edit - Just noticed that if you want to run the debug version (runnerw.exe) you will need to add the a config file (with same xml as above) named `runnerw.exe.config` also.

Found the config details at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/dd409252(v=vs.100)